# Opencart total product price multiply by custom option

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have searched for a module but I don't think any meet my requirements.

I have the product (business cards) then the following options:

```
Single/Double sided: Single,Double

Quantity: 500 s,1000 s ,2000 s, 500 d, 1000 d, 2000 d 
(dependenton Single/Double sided)

Delivery type: Standard,Express
```

I need it to do something like this

```
total product price = (item price + option(s) price)* delivery
```

The delivery option would need a value set to 1 for standard delivery and 1.15 for express

Could I use the weight value as it is unnecessary for delivery, or would I have to add a new column to the product_option_value table, and if so how do I do that.

I am aware the above is pseudo code I just used the code blocks so it was easier to read

Answer (score 0):

I think
you can use the Flat delivery method as Standard and Per Item Delivery method as Express

```
//extension>shipping enable Per Item delivery & configure it to 1.5 each
```

Now pass your Product Quantity Option in product by Product Option and configure the product price according to Product Quantity Price

```
// catalog>options create called Quantity and values 500 s,1000 s ,2000 s, 500 d, 1000 d, 2000 d 
// catalog>product>option add qty and configure price according to qty
// catalog>product>Data product price to 1
```

Now you need to hide the default qty box in product page of tpl because qty is passed by qty option now, and you need to overwrite the qty input value according to the selected value of Qty options so that qty will help to calculate the product delivery rate and qty from qty option will help to determine product price

Hope this helps